# How do I decode `mailto:` link to more readable form?

Tags: command-line, mailto

Is there a simple tool that just dumps the content of a mailto link to console?

```
$ decode_mailto 'mailto:a@b.c?subject=qqq&body=www%20eee&'
To: a@b.c
Subject: qqq

www eee
```

Comment: Why not just click on it, and it will appear in your e-mail client, correctly formatted? You don't have to send it.

Comment: The `mailto:` link may be generated outside normal desktop environment where e-mail client may work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat decode_mailto 
#!/bin/bash
perl -lpe 's/%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg;s/mailto:/To: /g;s/subject=/Subject: /g;s/body=/\n/g;s/[&?]/\n/g'

$ chmod 755 decode_mailto 

$ echo 'mailto:a@b.c?subject=qqq&body=www%20eee&' | ./decode_mailto
To: a@b.c
Subject: qqq

www eee


$
```

Comment: Update for actual HEX-code, not just bare DEC-numbers (mindlapse).